# как преобразовать Буквы в числовые значения

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста функцию на PHP преобразования Букв в числовые значения
например

313.6K=313600

4.2M=4200000

```
function Convert($num) { 
    preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]/', $num, $lat); //print_r($textArray); 

    if ($lat[0]=='K'){ 
        $k= preg_replace('/[^\d.]/','',$num); 
        return $k*1000; 
    } 

    if ($lat[0]=='M'){ 
        $k= preg_replace('/[^\d.]/','',$num); 
        return $k*1000000; 
    }       
    
    return $num; 
} 

echo Convert('789.9M');
```

Comment: function Convert($num){
 
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]/', $num, $lat);
//print_r($textArray);

if ($lat[0]=='K'){
$k= preg_replace('/[^\d.]/','',$num);
return $k*1000; 
}
if ($lat[0]=='M'){
$k= preg_replace('/[^\d.]/','',$num);
return $k*1000000; 
}

return $num;
}


echo Convert('789.9M');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function byteconvert($value) {
    preg_match('/(.+)(.{2})$/u', $value, $matches);
    list($_,$value,$unit) = $matches;
    return (int) ($value * pow(1024, array_search(strtolower($unit), array(1 => 'Кб','Мб','Гб','Тб'))));
}


echo byteconvert('4.2Мб');
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо очень-очень выручил

Comment: @Павел если решение помогло - можно ткнуть галочку рядом с ответом :)